# What is this syntax in html file

Tags: html, reactjs

```
<% if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { %>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
    ></script>
    <% } %>
```

I found the above code in my `index.html`. From the look of it I understand that it's to decide to load the react js from CDN.

This might be obvious but I have no web background and I'm wondering what's the syntax known as? And generally will be used in what scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is basically two parts. 1) would be including the `script` files and 2) would be the condition for on which environment it would be *executed*

Look at this line `if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {` and what is basically means is that those `scripts` would only be included to your `index.html` if its in the `production` environment.

Generally, you use these type of conditions like `process.env.NODE_ENV`, when you want to include, execute *anything* or a certain environment for your application.

The Syntax ins EJS. Keep in mind you can use `<% something %>` when you try to execute code & `<%= %>` when you try to populate something.
It can also be ASP.NET based on your framework and application language. *FYI: Ruby also uses the same syntax*

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. My question is more of asking the name for the syntax `<%` and in what cases are we using it

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is called [EJS](https://ejs.co/). It's a JavaScript template engine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link and answer